# GPU Panic: OS X 10.11, El Capitan stability issues and spontaneous restarts

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I am facing severe stability issues after doing a clean install of OS X 10.11, El Capitan, on my MacBook Pro (Mid 2010).

It restarts spontaneously for no apparent reason. Sometimes it subsequently reports a kernel panic, while other times not. Also it seems to affect the battery, such that the maximum charge varies before and after a crash, e.g. just now it was 105% before and 63% after.

Before the clean install a brand new original battery and a new SSD (Crucial CT250MX200SSD1) was installed.

I did try an SMC reset, but with no effect.

I have no idea what is going on. Any similar experiences or ideas?

#### Hardware

- MacBookPro6,2, 15-inch, Mid 2010
- 2,66 GHz Intel Core i7
- 8 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

#### Kernel Panic

```
Anonymous UUID:       C5463F05-8C33-1513-0EE0-791D992DAC46

Wed Oct 21 08:01:33 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f9d212bad): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff     0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff9136332000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.11.31.1/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9125363440 : 0xffffff801a0e5357 
0xffffff91253634c0 : 0xffffff7f9d212bad 
0xffffff91253635a0 : 0xffffff7f9ad81fa4 
0xffffff9125363660 : 0xffffff7f9ae4eadd 
0xffffff91253636a0 : 0xffffff7f9ae4eb48 
0xffffff9125363720 : 0xffffff7f9b0d3a23 
0xffffff9125363890 : 0xffffff7f9ae72b79 
0xffffff91253638b0 : 0xffffff7f9ad88cfd 
0xffffff9125363960 : 0xffffff7f9ad86690 
0xffffff9125363b60 : 0xffffff7f9ad8891f 
0xffffff9125363c50 : 0xffffff7f9c6b53da 
0xffffff9125363cb0 : 0xffffff7f9c6b206b 
0xffffff9125363d30 : 0xffffff7f9c69c649 
0xffffff9125363d60 : 0xffffff7f9c65986a 
0xffffff9125363d80 : 0xffffff7f9c66a033 
0xffffff9125363db0 : 0xffffff7f9c669ed0 
0xffffff9125363e00 : 0xffffff7f9c669d7d 
0xffffff9125363e50 : 0xffffff7f9c66a01d 
0xffffff9125363e80 : 0xffffff7f9c659eee 
0xffffff9125363ed0 : 0xffffff7f9c65771b 
0xffffff9125363ef0 : 0xffffff801a6b7226 
0xffffff9125363f40 : 0xffffff801a6b5091 
0xffffff9125363f80 : 0xffffff801a6b5186 
0xffffff9125363fb0 : 0xffffff801a1d14b7 
  Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.11.31)[181BAD29-8BC7-398F-B079-2544FF3B0E04]@0xffffff7f9d204000->0xffffff7f9d217fff
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.11.31)[1302F5C4-F57D-3810-9205-9803402BB462]@0xffffff7f9d1fc000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[CBAE26D8-0ACB-3C1F-8347-FDCA67EC40B3]@0xffffff7f9abb4000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[668E3DEE-F98E-3456-92D6-F4FEEA355A72]@0xffffff7f9a92d000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[48AC8EA9-BD3C-3FDC-908D-09850215AA32]@0xffffff7f9acd4000
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[5CB7D4B7-B100-34EE-BD40-1EC07E865C67]@0xffffff7f9d1ff000
     com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f9ad2b000->0xffffff7f9afa0fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[668E3DEE-F98E-3456-92D6-F4FEEA355A72]@0xffffff7f9a92d000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[814A7F4B-03EF-384A-B205-9840F0594421]@0xffffff7f9ad1b000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[48AC8EA9-BD3C-3FDC-908D-09850215AA32]@0xffffff7f9acd4000
     com.apple.GeForceTesla(10.0)[1F75910B-9AD6-3258-BAFD-1C7998CB38F7]@0xffffff7f9c651000->0xffffff7f9c71cfff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[668E3DEE-F98E-3456-92D6-F4FEEA355A72]@0xffffff7f9a92d000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[814A7F4B-03EF-384A-B205-9840F0594421]@0xffffff7f9ad1b000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[48AC8EA9-BD3C-3FDC-908D-09850215AA32]@0xffffff7f9acd4000
        dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f9ad2b000
     com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(10.0)[56199CA6-3C8D-3EBB-B5EF-7B1B4678ACF9]@0xffffff7f9afab000->0xffffff7f9b258fff
        dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(10.0.0)[05FC5D7E-BB0B-3232-BBBD-8A49B6870D8B]@0xffffff7f9ad2b000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[668E3DEE-F98E-3456-92D6-F4FEEA355A72]@0xffffff7f9a92d000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15A284

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Wed Aug 26 16:57:32 PDT 2015; root:xnu-3247.1.106~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 37BC582F-8BF4-3F65-AFBB-ECF792060C68
Kernel slide:     0x0000000019e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801a000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8019f00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3595765670560
last loaded kext at 9188353999: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f9c94e000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 124186672648: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUHCI   1.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9b640000, size 126976)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.19
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.50
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.50
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.0f4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   10.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.0f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.11.31
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 37
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.7.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.11
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.11.31
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.50
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.0f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.0f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.11.31
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.50
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.50
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.8
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1100.23
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 414
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B10, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2,66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533641465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533641465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.0f4 16320, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Crucial_CT250MX200SSD1, 250,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Built-in iSight
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add some of the kernel panic log file. You can find the file using **Applications > Utilities > Console.app** then look under **System Diagnostic Reports**.

Comment: I just added the newest kernel panic report. I hope someone has an idea as to what is going on. It is quite difficult to use a laptop, which spontaneously restarts every hour or so

Comment: According to this [link](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/gpu-kernel-panic-in-mid-2010-whats-the-best-fix.1890097/) the GPU Kernel Panic in mid-2010 macbook pros is a known issue. The strange part is, that it has not been a problem on Mavericks. It only started occurring after I clean installed El Capitan.

Comment: Update: I called Apple support earlier today. They led me through doing a SMC reset and a NVRAM reset. Also OS X El Capitan 10.11 was re-installed. I just had another crash so still the issue is not resolved. I will call them again tomorrow.

Comment: I found this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203554) according to which it does not look like any solution other than expensive hardware replacement exists: "MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) intermittent black screen or loss of video Quality Program has ended
The eligibility period for the MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) intermittent black screen or loss of video Quality Program has ended." :-(

Comment: Update: Since installing 10.11.1 this morning, I have had no GPU kernel panics. As the issue is related to a hardware failure on the Nvidia discrete graphics chip, I am not quite sure if I am out of the woods just yet with a mere software update. I will keep you and any future readers posted.

Comment: Update: No solution so far. My MBP is still unstable. I have talked extensively with Apple support and they have now referred me to an official Apple retailer to ask for a repair.

Comment: I have the same configuration which causes the GPU panic as well. No solution found so far, just wanted to mention there is an other case.

Comment: Update: My MBP has now been checked by an authorised apple service provider end the logic board needs to be replaced. Price 800 euros. I'm not going to spend that much money on a 5 year old laptop. Next step is to call Apple support and see if they are willing to cover the repair. I doubt it though...

Comment: Update: Talked extensively with Apple support. They were quite friendly and all, but alas they cannot cover the 800 euro repair, that my local AASP charges. I will decline the repair and instead I plan to take the laptop to an electronics repair shop, where they possibly can refurbish the faulty connections between the logic board and the GPU, which is the physical cause of the kernel panics.

Answer (score 3):

There was a quality program for 2010 15" MacBook pros where the graphics card would fail in a mode very similar to what you are seeing. If you go to an Apple Store, if your model is one of the affected ones, they have a special diagnostic to test specifically for the issue.

That being said, since it's about 5 years old now, it might be vintage and no longer qualify for a quality program or any repair for that matter. But at least you'll know if your problem is hardware or software. (Apple doesn't charge for the appointment or running a diagnostic)

Comment: There is a similar quality program for later model MacBook Pros: http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: For what it's worth, my 2011 15" MacBook Pro was long out of warranty, and when the graphics card failed I was prepared to pay several hundred dollars for the replacement card.  (I'd never heard of the quality program.)  But, surprise!  When I took it in for repairs I learned about the quality program and the repairs were done for free!

Comment: **Important note:** The first Apple technician I talked to **did not know about the quality program** (or just didn't tell me—she seemed new, though).  After I took the computer home to make a backup (via "target disk mode" and CarbonCopyCloner) and brought it back for repairs, **the *second* tech I talked to told me about the quality program,** and that my repairs would be free.

Answer (score 3):

I went to the Genius Bar after the same kernel panics (posted above) and spontaneous crash/restarts (after the 10.11 upgrade). I knew the mid-2010 MacBook Pro had a graphics chip problem before I went, however it was never a problem. They did the diagnostic and (sure enough) Apple Techs said I needed a new logic board (where the graphics chip mounts). I said that it only became a problem with the El Capitan upgrade. Circular logic prevailed in our discussion - a sort of chicken and egg philosophical debate.

The tech (who shall remain unnamed) said "Look, just downgrade your OS to the previous version and it will be fine." So, I did. And, it's now working fine (no more crashes) with the older, but more reliable, OS 10.6.8

This was a really lousy Mac experience. However, the fix was as easy as a few drag and drops to a spare drive and a Time Machine session.

Comment: I've got about three Macs that otherwise were stable and started crashing badly with this GPU panic on 10.11 - I'll update back if I can get a stable build less than 10.11 and greater than 10.6.8 - perhaps it's something we can keep using the Macs for occasional use on legacy projects and legacy software rather than updating them to 10.11.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System Preferences > Energy Saver` and **uncheck** `Automatic graphics switching`. It resolved my problem on El Capitan.

This issue is caused when your Mac is transitioning from the integrated GPU to the second, discrete GPU.
I have the same Mac configuration, and it restarts when I open high-resolution apps like Photos, HD videos on YouTube, and sometimes Launchpad.

I also recommend you download [gfxCardStatus](https://gfx.io/) to see when your apps are switching GPUs (should you choose not to disable automatic graphics switching).

Comment: I just looked and this option is already unchecked

Comment: This also happens not only during video switching.

Comment: LeonDK, let me know please if your GPU kernel panics completely disappeared after updating El Capitan.

Comment: @SmailK No unfortunately, they started after I installed El Capitan. I have found NO solution so far. As I understand it, the issue is that El Capitan require more graphic ressources, hence the frequency of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same configuration - and the same GPU panic - the only difference being the addresses.  My 8-Gig of RAM is from Crucial and has worked flawlessly for 3 years.  I have been troubleshooting for several weeks and I can almost "cause" the panic to occur.  Note:  I get the same panic whether upgrading to El Capitan - or after a clean install.  Multiple SMC / NVRAM resets have made no difference.  I can't say yet whether unchecking the automatic graphics switching option makes any difference.  It is also the same whether running on battery or AC power.  Here are my observations so far.

1. When the GPU panic occurs - the Mac Mail app is open with mail and side bar fully displayed or partially obscured behind another window.  Safari has typically been open as well.
2. The GPU panic occurs shortly after wake from sleep when the trackpad or mouse is used to scroll through mail messages.
3. I made it 13 days without the panic (but I also never opened the mail app during that time - since this is not my primary Mac - I was able to avoid using Mail).  Safari was open during this entire time.  All other activities were my typical daily activities.  As soon as I opened Mail - and allowed the Mac to go to sleep - within 10 seconds of waking from sleep and scrolling the list of emails - the panic occurs.
4. It seems that the Mac also has to be sleeping for a certain period of time before the panic will occur.  It is not necessarily possible to cause the panic to occur by intentionally telling the Mac to sleep - and then waking it shortly after.  If left in sleep for 20 minutes or longer - the panic is more likely to occur.
5. I will continue to troubleshoot - with "only" the mail app open - and also with sleep set to "never".

Comment: Update: I have confirmed that GPU Panic occurs regardless of the Automatic Graphics Switching setting.

Comment: Update: I have now determined that the GPU panic can be reliably re-produced by having the mail app open - but partially obscured behind another window - so that it does not have the focus - and then either put the Mac to sleep - or allow it to sleep on its own - for about 15 minutes or more.  Wake the Mac - can manipulate other windows and apps just fine - as soon as mail regains the focus - and I scroll up and down in the list of mails - the GPU panic occurs.  Taking to Apple Store this afternoon for hardware test.  I will submit a bug report if there is no indication of a hardware issue.

Comment: Update:  Apple Store tested my Mid 2010 15" MacBook Pro.  On their advanced graphics part of the test it failed on the Metal API test (or so they said) - they showed me the failure.  Video board (on logic board) is failing.  The logic board needs to be replaced.  I'm questioning whether the video board has always had this problem - and the problem is now surfacing because El Capitan is using the Metal API.  If enough people bring in their Mid 2010 MacBook pro and this same failure occurs - maybe Apple will refund the logic board replacement cost.  No need to report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting similar problems on a mid-2012 retina mbpro with el capitan.

It only started happening yesterday but many times since.

Whenever it has occurred, the computer has been running seriously hot. I am not using smcFanControl at high intensity and monitoring the temperatures with Temperature Gauge to see if it happens at low temperatures as well. But it may be a problem that's provoked by intense GPU usage.

Another clue mentioned here is that (apart from hardware problems) it might have to do with which kernel extensions are loaded: https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/7592234

Here is my kernel panic log: http://pastebin.com/hci9xBKW

Edit: perhaps using really GPU intensive things like going back and forth in youtube videos can stress it and potentially provoke it for testing purposes...

Answer (score 0):

I hope that someone gives you a precise answer like update your duet software or unplug this specific piece of hardware, but you may have to do the manual troubleshooting labor and record each instance of the panic in order to narrow down what's causing it.

That process is extremely easy but a little time-consuming:

1. Make sure your data is backed up  at intervals that makes sense for you.
2. [How serious are occasional kernel panics?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74209/how-serious-are-occasional-kernel-panics)

You can then ignore occasional kernel panics and be meticulous about troubleshooting ones that are repeatable. Keep in mind, how repeatable a panic is can be hard to estimate until you have 10 or more instances and can look back over specific logs and circumstances. These logs also make it far easier to decide whether to repair hardware or focus on software repair and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same MBPconfiguration and have been having the same GPU crashes but far more frequently - every 10 minutes in xcode.  I did download the gfxcardstatus tool and set it to internal display only and have now been running for about 45 minutes with no crashes ... so this may not be a complete test but it does seem better. FWIW ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a 2010 MacBook Pro. Upgrade to Yosemite. It slowed down so I upgraded to El Capitan. It got worse. Took it in for diagnostics and it failed on video main logic card..?

They took it for about a week to fix it. I am really nervous about them messing it up even more. It will cost $310.00. It was working fine before the upgrade. I had to upgrade because they said it was not compatible with my I-phone 5S.

So long story short, this appears to be something that can be fixed for a flat rate repair. Less than $350 for parts, labor and shipping. Really disappointed with Mac as I hoped to not need to pay for a repair so soon.

Comment: $350 is much cheaper than the repair offer I received. They would charge ~€800, which is about $875