# MacBook Pro crash after sleeping for a long time

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2016) running macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2659). Recently I found out that if I left my machine sleeping for a long amount of time (about 15+ hours), it will cause a kernel panic and restart itself so when I open my computer the next time it will tell me the computer have shutdown unexpectedly. Is this a software bug or my computer have problem?

**EDIT:**

I got this problem today. The shutdown cause is `-128`. Maybe a hardware failure? Also sometimes instead of a crash, I also have [this problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/275190/162149). (I posted that as a separate question since it's not a crash). [Here is the crash report](http://pastebin.com/Xrkm0184).

Comment: Did you have any thing running before you put your computer to sleep that could have gone horrifically  wrong?

Comment: @OzzieSpin Nope, nothing is running, just Finder

Comment: Same thing happens to me, but with much shorter sleep times. Any luck?

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue with my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014). If I clamshell, if I walk away for 1 minute, if the screensaver is invoked, and sometimes when I use Lock Screen, my computer screen will go black and shutdown. Logs are inconclusive, with not much information. The only thing that I see repeating over and over is that "com.apple.quicklook" always has a crash behavior right before the shutdown happens.

Comment: Have a look at this [Question/Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212809/shutdown-cause-128/212810#212810)  I would get the hardware checked out.

Comment: @Allan yep, probably have to hit up at Apple since the memory is soldered on.

Answer (score 1):

Occasional kernel panics are more nanannoyance than something to be fixed.

- [How serious are occasional kernel panics?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74209/how-serious-are-occasional-kernel-panics)

However, if you can make them happen, there is a process to resolve them:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553

Answer (score -1):

It just happened to me today, out of the blue so to speak. Anyway, after powering down and restarting several times (with no success) I powered back up in Safe mode (holding the Shift key down). That didn't help because my MacBook froze again. BUT, when I powered up again (without Safe mode), the problem was solved. Go figure.