# 2016 MacBook Pro shutdowns when the lid is close with cause 0

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, shutdown

My 15-inch 2016 MacBook Pro is now experiencing shutdowns when the lid is closed. Though it is not a crash because I don't get a crash report when I turn the computer back on (unlike the problem I had earlier). I used the following Terminal command to obtain the Previous Shutdown Cause (as the console app can't do it anymore in Sierra):

```
log show --style syslog --last 48h | egrep shutdown\ cause | awk -F')' '{print substr($0,1,19), $NF}'
```

The code for the shutdown is 0. From [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126588/162149) I found that 0 triggers when you unplugged the battery, or the power cable on desktop Macs. But the battery on the 2016 MacBook Pro is non-removable (obviously). Even more strangely, when this happens, my laptop is plugged into the power adapter and for sure it is charging. This doesn't happen when I am using the computer both on battery and power adapter, it only happens when the lid is closed for a while.

I have tried to reset SMC and NVRAM with no luck. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: This and your other [question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/262528/119271) points to a logic board failure.  To get a 0 shutdown cause you have disconnect all power and on a laptop that's pretty hard to do.  I suspect there's something wrong with the SMC or related components and not enough power is getting to critical systems like memory so you are seeing the shutdowns/crashes.

Comment: @Allan yeah, thought of that. Going to get it fixed.

Comment: Let us know what happens.

Comment: the same has happened to me. Very disappointed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had been close to year after posting this original question. The MacBook is completely fine now. It has to be some bugs that Apple had in the 2016 revision of the MBP. I’ve been running for a close to half a year without any problem now (it hadn’t even crashed once after 10.13). If you still had the same question you might want to get the machine serviced as I’m pretty sure if it’s that then it’s a logic board problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible hardware issues aside, check what is your setting on what the computer wants to do when you close the lid and the behaviour afterwards. You can see the settings with the:

```
pmset -g
```

Look for the *hibernatemode*, *autopoweroffdelay* and *standbydelay* settings.

See a blog post describing the pmset settings [here](http://bendeegan.com/2016/04/19/how-to-make-a-mac-hibernate-properly-and-consistently/)

On the hardware problems side I've read reports that a faulty charger might cause the MacBook to shutdown. As you report that the problem does not occur when on battery life, this may be the culprit and I'd suggest you try a different charger.

Is the time you mention "for a while" three hours or more? Then the problem occurs when your MacBook tries to enter the standby (see standbydelay setting above).